# Ember.js Accessing Json Side-loading

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data, promise

I have got a json file like this and in the route I call the people model

```
{
  "people": [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "person1",
    "clothes": ["one trouser","another trouser"]
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "person2",
    "clothes": ["one trouser","another trouser"]
   }
  ],
  "trousers": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "trouser1",
    "madeby": ["one worker","another worker"]
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "trouser2",
    "clothes": ["one worker","another worker"]
   }
 ]
}
```

In the controller, in a computed property I try to retrieve one "trouser" like this:

```
OneTrouser: function(){
    return this.store.find('trouser',1).then(function(trouser){
         return trouser;
});
}.property(),
```

In the view, I try to access it with {{OneTrouser}} but it renders: [object Object]

If I try to iterate over it with and each:

```
The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {_id: 111, _label: undefined, _subscribers: }
```

How can I access it? I know that inside the .then function its well formed.

And would it be possible to call a trouser by name instead of by id?

Comment: Try `{{OneTrouser.name]]`

Comment: can you log `{{log OneTrouser}}` and view it in Firebug? See what's in there?

Comment: done, inside _data is what I am looking for, how could I access that?

Comment: {{OneTrouser.name}} should work, shouldnt it?

Comment: Seems like it should. Can you post something on JSbin?

Answer (score 0):

calling trouser by name i think if you simply follow the docs as below you can achieve it

```
var peters = this.store.find('person', { name: "Peter" });
```

btw I assume

```
OneTrouser: function(){
    return this.store.find('trouser',1).then(function(trouser){
         return trouser;
});
}.property(),
```

code is in you controller. you should avoid doing store.find in controller. let routes model hook do it and in controller you can set OneTrouser by using something like filterBy(key,value) in your case i think key will be name

here is detail explaination of your side loading[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027412/ember-data-accessing-a-list-of-sideloaded-resources)

### **UPDATES**

you are right sideloading will load trousers.If I am not wrong you are looking for filter method [Filter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter) . a jsbin will be really helpful.

as far as i understand

```
this.store.all() //will only call records in store
this.store.find() //will call record in store if not present fetch from server
this.store.filter() // will create a dynamic array i.e will be update if you fetch records from some other means
 //you can optionally make this.store.filter to fetch from server by passing query
```

yes and find will make a call to server if record does not exist if you are trying to call records from store only use all. `this.store.all()`

Comment: In the route I am calling "people", the goal of doing side-loading is not to make 2 calls but one, in theory "trousers" are loaded with this first call to retrieve "people", how could I access it then in the controller?